# "cURL error 28: Resolving timed out" on Wordpress on Azure App Service on Linux

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, docker, azure-web-app-service

My Wordpress installation on Azure App Service on Linux using a custom Docker container has very slow response times. Pages take around 20-40 seconds to load.

I have a troubleshooting plugin installed which indicates the problem is "cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after N milliseconds" when making requests to the following URLs

- https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/
- http://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/
- https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check/1.1/
- http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check/1.1/
- https://api.wordpress.org/themes/update-check/1.1/
- http://api.wordpress.org/themes/update-check/1.1/

[image: curl errors]

cURL works fine on the scm-site command line. For example this works OK.

```
curl -X POST http://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/
```

**Edit**
If i ssh into the container and run this php code, it works fine.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/';

$fields = array(
    'version' => urlencode('4.8.1'),
    'php' => urlencode('7.1.8'),
    'locale' => urlencode('fi'),
    'mysql' => urlencode('5.6.26.0'),
    'local_package' => urlencode('fi'),
    'blogs' => urlencode('1'),
    'users' => urlencode('4'),
    'multisite_enabled' => urlencode('0'),
    'initial_db_version' => urlencode('26691')
);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

It returns the following.

```
root@71c3bba3a35e:/home/site/wwwroot# php curl.php
{"offers":[{"response":"upgrade","download":"http:\/\/downloads.wordpress.org\/release\/wordpress-4.8.1.zip","locale":"en_US","packages":{"full":"http:\/\/downloads.wordpress.org\/release\/wordpres
s-4.8.1.zip","no_content":"http:\/\/downloads.wordpress.org\/release\/wordpress-4.8.1-no-content.zip","new_bundled":"http:\/\/downloads.wordpress.org\/release\/wordpress-4.8.1-new-bundled.zip","par
tial":false,"rollback":false},"current":"4.8.1","version":"4.8.1","php_version":"5.2.4","mysql_version":"5.0","new_bundled":"4.7","partial_version":false}],"translations":[]}
```

My Docker image uses php:7.1.8-apache.

Here is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM php:7.1.8-apache
EXPOSE 80 443 2222

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ssl-cert \
    ca-certificates \
    apt-utils \
    vim \
    curl \
    mysql-client \
    openssh-server \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libicu-dev \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
mcrypt \
mysqli \
json \
mbstring \
curl \
intl \
&& echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd \
&& ln -s /home/LogFiles /var/log/apache2

ENV APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2 \
APACHE_ENVVARS=/etc/apache2/envvars \
APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2 \
APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2 \
APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2 \
APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid \
APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data \
APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

WORKDIR /usr/local
COPY config/wprun.sh config/wp-config.php /usr/local/
COPY config/sshd_config /etc/ssh/
COPY config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/


RUN chmod 755 wprun.sh && \
rm -R /var/www/html && \
a2enmod rewrite && \
a2enmod expires && \
a2enmod include && \
sed -i "s@/var/www@/home/site/wwwroot@" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf && \
sed -i "s@/var/www@/home/site/wwwroot@" /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

CMD ["/bin/bash","wprun.sh"]
```

**Edit 2**
This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/docksal/docksal/issues/312) seems similar. There is a suggestion to use [OpenDNS resolvers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-solve-curl-error-28-resolving-timed-out-after-10518-milliseconds). Could this be a DNS issue? If so, then how does this work with Docker and Azure?

**Edit 3**
This seems to be a DNS issue. This is the resolv.conf file in Azure.

```
search reddog.microsoft.com
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options timeout:1 attempts:5 ndots:0
```

When i change nameserver to 8.8.8.8, pages load in one to two seconds. Also all the cURL errors go away.

If i understand correctly, [Docker mounts the host machine's resolv.conf file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns) and DNS settings should be set with Docker run command options. It's not recommended to change these files directly.

> The exact details of how Docker manages the DNS configurations inside
>   the container can change from one Docker version to the next. So you
>   should not assume the way the files such as /etc/hosts,
>   /etc/resolv.conf are managed inside the containers and leave the files
>   alone and use the following Docker options instead.

However, it doesn't seem possible to set docker run parameters in Azure.

Comment: can you get inside the docker container and check if that works? Also are you using the apache with wordpress or nginx with wordpress?

Comment: I updated my post. It seems to be working inside the container. And i'm using apache.

Answer (score 0):

The scm-site command line for curl works on the host machine of Azure WebApps for Linux, not inside the docker container.

There is an issue [curl fails inside container on https connection](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2011) on GitHub `moby/moby`, which is very similar with yours. According to this, I think you need to set the `--tlsv1` option via the PHP method `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');` for your curl call inside the docker container of Azure WebApp for Linux.

Hope it helps.

Comment: According to this scm-site should work inside the container [SSH support for Azure Web Apps for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-ssh-support).


I'm not so sure about that GitHub issue being similar because i have problems with http requests also.

Comment: I tried running curl with php inside the container on my own machine and it's  working fine. I ran the same script as in my post.