# Azure App Service - Wordpress super slow and cURL error 28

Tags: wordpress, azure

Following the announcement found here https://azure.github.io/AppService/2022/08/08/Announcing-GA-WordPress-on-Azure-App-Service.html

I've decided to migrate my website from a Ubuntu Server VM on Azure to this App Service configuration.

First, I've created new resources using the "Wordpress" template/configuration which I found on Azure portal. So, the deployment process created an App Service (plan P1), a MySQL database and a CDN Endpoint.

Everything seems to working quite fine. Then I've moved my website files from the VM to the App Service and I've created a new database in MySQL server where I've imported my website database without problems.
I've kept the `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` folders which were deployed by Azure and the wp-config.php file.

As final step, I've changed the configurations in the App Service to connect to the right database.

Then I tried to visit my website, but it is super slow (about 10 seconds to load the home page and I was forced to disable some plugins which was causing a fatal error).
I've checked the Wordpress Health Status using the plugin in the admin center, and it reports some issues.

Two of them are reporting a message like this:

```
cURL error 28: Resolving timed out
```

I've seen another post on SO (["cURL error 28: Resolving timed out" on Wordpress on Azure App Service on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155659/curl-error-28-resolving-timed-out-on-wordpress-on-azure-app-service-on-linux)) with a similar issue and it suggested to change resolv.conf DNS to 8.8.8.8 (previously was 127.0.0.11). The author of the post wrote that this change improved page load time to max 1-2 seconds.
I've made this change but then the website stopped working returning "Error establishing a database connection" (maybe because MySQL db and app service are on the VNET created by Azure Wordpress template and there are some restriction to connect to database).

I've also tried to disable the CDN, changing the `CDN_ENABLED` to false in the App Service configuration. Obviously I've created the correct custom domains in the App Service and changed the domain DNS which is managed outside Azure.

Also, and I don't know if it is all related to this issue, I've noticed that Google Page Speed is unable to reach the website reporting the error "Lighthouse encountered an error loading the requested page".

What can I do to resolve the reported cURL error 28 and maybe these performance issues?

Comment: As far as I remember, Wordpress runs multiple queries to the database. This is an expensive task and should be avoided when possible. Try to enable a good plugin cache such as wp total cache, this will generate cached version of your pages and will speedup the load time. Other than that, check if it's missing some important connection string parameter (thread pools, etc).

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio thanks for your comment. For example trying to install the plugin you suggested (which is deployed also by Azure Wordpress template) I receive an error: "504.0 GatewayTimeout". I mean, this should not be related to database queries. Don't you think VNet or DNS configuration could be related to my issue?

Comment: really hard to help without looking into the environment, but it seems to me, there's some wrong when trying to resolve some dns entry. it could be when trying to connect to the database or something else.